# Post to external URL using Experience Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am new to Sitecore Forms (SC 9.3).

What I want to achieve seems very simple, can't believe it's not possible in Sitecore.

I just want to create a simple form with 1 field (E-mail) and have it posted to an external URL.

The final HTML needs to look something like this:

```
<form action="https://my-custom-url.com" method="POST">

 <input type="text" name="" id="">
 <input type="submit" ... />
</form>
```

That's all. But I can't find a way to do such a simple thing!

Thanks.

Note: I now there's a "redirect" feature, but that's not what I am looking for. I just want to post the form to a custom URL - that's all.

Comment: Do you need to use Experience Forms for this? What is the purpose of posting to an external URL?

Comment: That's not what experience forms is designed for. You could instead add a custom submit action to post to the external url.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I want to post a few fields to ClickDimensions. ClickDimensions receives the post data, saves it in CRM and redirects the user to a "return Url" (configurable). Maybe that's not the intention of Experience Forms, like said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom Submit action and insert that on your Submit button in form builder.
You can see on this example 2 submit actions, one is custom: "Submit To Service Bus" and "Redirect to Page" OOTB.

[image]

check on sitecore link. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action.html

Comment: Thanks. Though I acknowledge this is not a solution that will work for my case in particular, I am considering the correct answer as it explains how to implement what was actually asked by me.